# Manage services on server - access denied

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've inherited a SharePoint 2010 small farm from my former colleague.
Somehow I don't see Manage services on server under the Service Applications in the central admin. 
When I'm trying to access this page directly (/_admin/Server.aspx) I'm getting Error: Access Denied. 
Portal seem to work otherwise fine.

1) I'm logging as a Farm administrator.

2) Central administration has been runned under elevated privileges (run as administrator), furthermore I've tried to run central admin in the IE (also with elevated privileges)

3) I'm the part of the local administrators group

4) UAC and IE ESC are disabled

Any advice what else should I check/do to get required access?

Comment: Are you browsing from the server hosting the central admin interface?

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't access central admin from the server hosting the admin interface. 
A possible workaround to fix this issue is to implement the loopback fix.